# Save user input to SharedPrefernces and set Value to EdiText

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I want to save user input to SharedPreferences when i click a button so that when a user launches the activity again the user input is set to the EditText and TextView. I already have a sharedPreferences File created that i save some text to in a previous activity.
I want update the SharedPreferences File with another details from this new activity that i created.

This is code for creating and saving to SharedPreferences

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "AuthUser";

prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
txtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);

    addIdButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddId);
    addIdButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            expiryDate = txtDate.getText().toString();
            edtIdNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtIdNumber);
            idNumber = edtIdNumber.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putInt("idType", idType);
            editor.putString("idNumber", idNumber);
            editor.putString("expiryDate", expiryDate);
            editor.apply();
        }
    });
```

This is my code to set the value from shared preferences to EditText and TextView

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    File f = new File(PREF_FILE_NAME);
    if (f.exists()){
        idType = prefs.getInt("idType", 0);
        idNumber = prefs.getString("idNumber", "");
        expiryDate = prefs.getString("expiryDate", "");

        edtIdNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtIdNumber);
        txtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        txtDate.setText(expiryDate);
        edtIdNumber.setText(idNumber);
        edtIdNumber.setText(idNumber);
        txtDate.setText(expiryDate);

    }
}
```

Comment: use onStart() code in OnCreate method.. becoze of you can find edittext after on create method execute....

Comment: The code looks fine. What is the issue you are facing. Apart from setting the text for `edtIdNumber` 2 times which is a copy paste mistake.

Comment: @PCGALIANDROID the issue is the values are not being saved to the sharedPreference file

Comment: I think that you are missing "commit" while writing to SharedPreferences. Try to add editor.commit(); and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File f = new File(PREF_FILE_NAME);` just has the name of the preference so 
`f.exists()` will always returns `false`

Solution : Remove

```
File f = new File(PREF_FILE_NAME);
if (f.exists()){
```

because if you don't have any value then simply use the default value

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    //File f = new File(PREF_FILE_NAME); // not a right path
    //if (f.exists()){ // false
        idType = prefs.getInt("idType", 0);
        idNumber = prefs.getString("idNumber", "");
        expiryDate = prefs.getString("expiryDate", "");

        edtIdNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtIdNumber);
        txtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        txtDate.setText(expiryDate);
        edtIdNumber.setText(idNumber);
        edtIdNumber.setText(idNumber);
        txtDate.setText(expiryDate);

    //}
}
```

Alternatively you can use [contains](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#contains(java.lang.String))

Comment: Your answer helped me. Thank you

Comment: i am glad that i could help, happy coding

Answer (score 1):

To Achive your work:
First of all try to understand difference between onCreate() and onStart() method of Activity in android, follow following url: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html 
-: use onCreate() method instead of onStart() for setting ui variables;

secondly change in your code like:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            expiryDate = txtDate.getText().toString();
            edtIdNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtIdNumber);
            idNumber = edtIdNumber.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putInt("idType", idType);
            editor.putString("idNumber", idNumber);
            editor.putString("expiryDate", expiryDate);
            editor.commit();
        }
```

Comment: this won't have any effect

Answer (score 0):

just remove `if (f.exists())` condition from `Onstart()` because `File f = new File(PREF_FILE_NAME);` just has the name of the preference so `f.exists()` will always returns false

**like below code**

```
     @Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
   /* File f = new File(PREF_FILE_NAME);
    if (f.exists()){*/
        idType = prefs.getInt("idType", 0);
        idNumber = prefs.getString("idNumber", "");
        expiryDate = prefs.getString("expiryDate", "");

        edtIdNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtIdNumber);
        txtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        txtDate.setText(expiryDate);
        edtIdNumber.setText(idNumber);
        txtDate.setText(expiryDate);


}
```